# JQuery Filtering Using Bootstrap Columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I have this working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p5ahob32/1/

```
    $('#filter').keyup(function () {

        var filter = $(this).val(), count = 0;

        $('.col-md-3 a').each(function () {
            // If the list item does not contain the text phrase fade it out
            if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
                $(this).fadeOut();

                // Show the list item if the phrase matches and increase the count by 1
            } else {
                $(this).show();

                count++;
            }
        });

        // Update the count
        var numberItems = count;
        $("#filter-count").text("Number of Clients = " + count);
    });
```

If you were to type 3 in the search box it would fade out all the other buttons except 3, however you will notice that the 3 button is all the way in the right because it is in a bootstrap column.

My question is how to I make it so that all the searched items will appear stacked nicely together at the top left?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get rid of all the rows except the outer one that wraps all the col's and hide parent of the `<a>`

```
$(this).parent().fadeOut();
//AND
$(this).parent().show()
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/p5ahob32/3/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

```
// change
$(this).fadeOut();

// to
$(this).parent().css("display","none");
// or 
$(this).parent().fadeOut()
```